# Print only subdirectories where file appears

Tags: shell, find

For a given file I want to list only the subdirectories where it appears.
I'm searching for the file using:

```
find . -name <filename> -print
```

but this is also printing the filename. 
I would also want to list subdirectories sorted by creation date. I'm sorting files like this:

```
find . -name test.txt -printf "%T@\t%Tc %6k KiB %p\n" | sort -n | cut -f 2-
```

Can someone help?

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for directories, so what about just building conditions that match the correct directories?

```
find . -type d -exec test -f {}/test.txt \; -print
```

This has the slight extra cost of spawning an `exec` for every file, but it's otherwise quick and simple.

Listing your results sorted by creation date may be problematic though. If the directory names are all simple -- alphanumeric with no special characters like newlines -- then you may be able to get away with letting `ls` take care of things:

```
ls -dt $(find . -type d -exec test -f {}/test.txt \; -print)
```

But beware of the dreaded [Parsing LS](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) risk.

Beyond that .. you could use [`stat`](http://man.freebsd.org/stat) to gather data information to sort, but its behaviour will depend on your operating system, or write something in an actual programming language that can handle filesystem data.